# Run angular-seed project inside of visual studio?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've created an Angularjs app by cloning the angular-seed.

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git Web
cd Web
npm install
```

Then the app can be started by running `npm start`.

I tried to create a new project and selected template "Javascript -> Node.js -> From Existing Node.js code". Then I set the start js file to `Web/app.app.js`. However, running (debug) the app got the following error?

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
 D:\....Web\app\app.js:4
angular.module('myApp', [
^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object. (D:\....\Web\app\app.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:590:10)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
 Press any key to continue...
```

**Update:**
I need to deploy the angular app on nodejs. How to create an angular project run on node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your getting confused as Angular will not run directly with node. Just open Visual Studio then select `File -> Open -> Website..` then browse to and select your `/Web` folder.

Once web site is open just make sure `app/index.html` is selected hit F5. It may ask you to alter web.config to enable debugging - or just if you just want to view it you can right click on `index.html` and View in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If angular is not defined then the AngularJS script has not loaded.

Comment: The app.js shouldn't be set as start script. How to make the VS open the index.html page instead?